# How to use a jQuery .load() call from anchor tag in dynamic content

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, modal-dialog

I have a search page that takes user input from a form, then sends that information to a PHP file which sends a cURL call to an outside server. The PHP file then takes the returned array from the server and echoes some HTML to a "results" div in the original search page.

What I'd like to do is set it up so when a user clicks on one of the line items in the "results" div, a modal window appears with more information about the individual item clicked.

I know how to create a jQuery script that will process a click on a single, unique link and generate the modal window by querying the server again (through a separate PHP file that formats the modal box with the additional information and sized correctly). What I *don't* know how to do is handle all of this with dynamically-created content.

Here's what the first PHP file echoes:

[removed at edit; see below]

It does that for each "listing" in the array returned by the server.

Here's what I've figured out for creating the modal window when the anchor tag in the #modalLaunch div is clicked (this comes from a test page I've been using to figure out how to manipulate the modal window and its content):

[removed at edit, see below]

I'm starting to suspect that I need to abandon this method entirely and try to use an "onClick" strategy, but again I have no idea how to pass the relevant pieces of information between all the functions. Help!

EDIT:

I did a really terrible job of asking this question. I'm sorry. Here's a better representation of the code I'm using:

**PHP File:**

($data is the array pulled from the outside server. I've removed a bunch of the extraneous variables, so just assume they map to something sensible.)

```
$data = unserialize($data);

$listings = $data["listings"];

echo "<ul id='listings_grid'>";

for($i=0;$i<$data["count"];$i++)
{
    $url = "/listings/".$listing_id;

    echo "<li>
            <a href='' target='_blank' data-listing-id='".$listing_id."'>
                    <div class='listing_thumb_image_container'>
                        <img class='listing_thumb_image' src='".$mainPhoto."'/>
                    </div>
                    <div class='listing_thumb_content'>
                        <br>Rent: $".$rent."
                        <br>Bedrooms: ".($bedrooms_count==0 ? "Studio" : ($bedrooms_count=='0.5' ? "Convertible" : $bedrooms_count))."
                        <br>Listing ID: ".$listing_id."
                    </div>
            </a>
        </li>";

}

echo "</ul>";
```

**The Search Page:**

(Again, pulling out a lot of excess.)

```
<?php
<script>

$(document).ready(function(){
$.post($("#html-form").attr("action"),$("#html-form").serialize(),function(data){
    $("#search_results").html(data);
});
});

$(document).ready(function(){
$("#html-form").on('change submit',function(){
    $.post($("#html-form").attr("action"),$("#html-form").serialize(),function(data){
        $("#search_results").html(data);
    });
    return false;
});
});

$(document).on('click','#search_results li',function(){
$('.modalDialog').css('display','block','opacity','1','pointer-events','auto');
var href = $(this).children('a').attr('href');
$('#openModalContent').load(href);
return false;
});

</script>

<div id="openModal" class="modalDialog">
<div>
    <a href="#close" title="Close" class="close">X</a>
    <div id="openModalContent"></div>
</div>

</div>

<div id="content">

<div id="search_form"><form></form></div>
<div id="search_results" style="margin:0 auto;"></div> 

</div>

<?php include ('footer.php'); ?>
```

So where do I go from here? For some reason, when I plug in the options presented by the answers so far, I'm not seeing the modal box appear. It might have to do with the CSS: currently, the modal window only becomes opaque when subjected to the :target pseudo-class. Suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want your dynamically generated content to be able to do stuff try this if your using JQuery 1.9 and above:

```
$(document).on('click','#openModalContent li',function(){
    var href = $(this).children('a').attr('href');
    $('#yourModalBox').load(href).show(888);
    return false;
});
```

Comment: I see where this is going, but I'm still having trouble actually generating the modal window. I've updated my code in the question to help explain myself better. Any thoughts on how this might change your suggestion? Thanks!

Comment: first of all you dont need to write $(document).ready(function(){ twice, just wrap all your JS code with it once. for $('.modalDialog').css just use $('.modalDialog').show(); and check your css for visibility and z-index and its position, be careful if you have position:static or absolute. Also try turning your Javascript off and setting .modalDialog with display block to see what it should look like. Also you are using a PHP opening tag before your script tag. Your page should fail and return a white screen. You need to close it.

Comment: Thanks for the help, Steve. I ended up using a similar strategy to what you posted, but I abandoned using CSS to manipulate the modal window and rewrote it using jQuery - the pseudo-class was giving me no end of trouble. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Add a data-listing-id attribute to the anchor in your generated HTML:

```
<a href='".$url."' target='_blank' data-listing-id='".$listing_id."'>
```

and use that attribute inside your click handler like:

```
$('#modalLaunch a').click(function(){
    $('#openModalContent').load('/listings.php', {id:$(this).data("listing-id")});
});
```

Comment: That's brilliant. How do I handle the "#modalLaunch a" issue? Obviously the .click() function will need to apply to each line item generated by the PHP function, so how do I reference the appropriate item?

Comment: Assuming that `#modalLaunch` is a parent (or parent of parent, etc) of your `li` elements, there is no issue to handle. `this` inside of the click handler function (see my answer) will point to the anchor that user has clicked on.

Comment: I don't think I did a very good job of explaining my code. I just tried again, having attempted your method (and failed miserably). Sorry for the trouble.